# Regarding FileInputStream and FileReader

Tags: java, io

Earlier I was using the below code to copy a file from source A to destination B. But I came to know that it can also be done through `FileReader`. But no data is being copied in destination file.

```
    FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("D:/A.txt");
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("D:/B.txt");
    int c;

    while((c=in.read() )!= -1)
        {
             System.out.println("Inside While");
             out.write(c);
        }
```

Comment: You need to call `out.close()` to make sure that the writes are flushed to disk.

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question. I need to copy one file from other and I am using FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:/A.txt");
  FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D:/B.txt"); .. How to from this

Comment: And As File Reader and File Input Stream both can do the same thing then what is the need of two

Comment: Hmmm. 1 Simple question, Do you want to make copy of file? (As it is) ?

Comment: Yes . That I am able to do with FileInputStream . I want from FileReader

Answer (score 0):

Add out.close() to make the copy happen.

InputStream is used to read binary data, So it will be slow. while Reader is used to read text data. you should probably use Reader in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy a file using FileReader and FileWriter:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\myfile.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:\\newfile.txt");
char[] buf = new char[1024];
int r = 0;
while ((r = fr.read(buf)) != -1) {
  fw.write(buf, 0, r);
}
fr.close();
fw.close();
```

It is important to close the writer after finishing the copy, otherwise the changes might not be flushed to disk.

Answer (score 0):

While reading data from file using FileInputStream data is read byte by byte, so its bound to be very slow. read() method from FileInputStream is a blocking method, which reads a byte of data or blocks if no input is yet available. It either returns next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.`This means we read one byte in each iteration of loop and prints it as Hexadecimal String. By the way, there is options to convert InputStream into byte array as well.`

On the other hand, when we use FileReader, we are reading data character by character. read() method from InputStreamReader, which is inherited by FileReader reads a single character and returns the character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. `This is why you see exactly same text as written in file output from our example 2.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. I provide two ways, one with reader and another is to use [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)),which is much much more cleaner to do that.

```
public class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File from =new File("E:\\share\\file1.txt");
        File to1=new File("E:\\share\\fileCopy1.txt");
        File to2=new File("E:\\share\\fileCopy2.txt");

        copyFileWithFiles(from, to1);
        copyFileWithFiles(from, to2);
    }


    //using Writer or Reader to copy
    public static void copyFileWithWriter(File from, File to) throws IOException{
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(from);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(to);) {

        char[] bytes = new char[1024];
        int hasRead = 0;
        while ((hasRead = fr.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fw.write(bytes, 0, hasRead);
        }
    }
    }

    //Use Files.copy 
    public static void copyFileWithFiles(File from, File to) throws IOException{
        Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );
    }
```

}

You must remember to close your resource(if you create Reader/Writer,inputStream/OutputStream), I see you do not do that in your post code.

If you are using java7 or above, you can use [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close for you ,just like above ,or, you need to `close()` by yourself. This is important!